# Sed error: unknown option to 's'

Tags: bash, sed

I have a sed command within a bash script that replaces the 10th line in a file with the value of a variable.
Ok to stop confustion (this is my fault, here is the complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Sync timezone between system and php

##get current timezone of system
line=$(head -n 1 /etc/sysconfig/clock)    
timezone=${line:6}

##Set up php date string
time="date_default_timezone_set('${timezone%?}');"
sed -i 10s|.*|$time| test.php
```

so time would have a value like:

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London')

Now gives these errors:

```
> test.php: Permission denied
> date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London);: Not such file or direcotry
> .: .:: is a directory
> sed: -e expression #1. char 3: unterminated 's' command
```

Any help would be great, and if you need any more info let me know!

Comment: That will replace the whole line with `$time`.  Don't you just want to replace part of the line, such as `$timezone`?

Comment: Yes another option would be to keep the line in test.php and just update the part that is $timezone. I was not sure how to do that so just did the whole line, but if you can do that, that would be great

Comment: This will replace the entire line with `$time`.  You will have a line in your PHP file with just `$time`.  Generally, that's invalid PHP. --Oh wait, I see...

Comment: Yes the php file line 10 is just $time this does work for my purpose

Comment: I was thinking that $time is a PHP variable, but it's a bash variable... never mind.

Comment: I believe the issue is that the `/` character appears in the value of the `$time` variable. You probably need to escape that, so that sed doesn't get confused.

Comment: `|` is the "pipe" character, so you should use something that's not special for the shell.  My answer uses `@`, which should work.  You could use `|` too but then you have to make sure you get your quoting/escaping correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `timezone` contains `/` character, you need to do something special:

```
sed -i 10s@.*@$time@ test.php
```

You can use any character that doesn't appear in your source and destination strings.  Here I chose `@`.

Comment: Thank you although all the above methods would work this was the one I went with

Answer (score 1):

```
time='date_default_timezone_set\("\$timezone"\);'
```

Note that I reversed the style of quotes, as well.  That's necessary because PHP won't substitute the variable when using single quotes.

You could also enclose $time in quotes, but if `$timezone` is an actual variable, you still need double quotes:

```
time='date_default_timezone_set("$timezone");'
sed -i 10s/.*/"$time"/ test.php
```

Based on your update to the question, my understanding is that you are actually using a string constant in place of `$timezone`, so this might not be applicable.  In this case, the cleanest option is to do:

```
time='date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");'
sed -i 10s/.*/"${time/\//\\/}"/ test.php
```

Note that this requires bash to be in "bash" mode, as opposed to "sh" mode.  Ensure that you have `#!/bin/bash` at the top of any scripts.

Comment: hm. i got strange error: `sed: 1: "test.php": undefined label 'est.php'`
by running the above code

Comment: @kobame Which set of code?  All of it works for me.

Comment: the last two lines, with the `sed -i 10s/.*/"${time/\//\\/}"/ test.php` - i put both into a file myscript and executed as `bash myscript` - my test.php contains only 20 lines of numbers

Comment: nah - just fugured out - need GNU sed - with the normal POSIX sed the script not working. when tried it with my `gsed` what is the gnu sed it works. Can you write it please POSIX compatible?

Comment: This should be POSIX-compatible; it's a pretty basic sed script.  The only thing that might not be POSIX-compatible is the quoting, which means that you would have to rely on the very first method, where everything is pre-escaped.  You'd have to check on that, though, as I don't know for sure.

Comment: That being said, there's nothing in here that looks like a sed label.  Are you sure that you aren't using the answer with the colons?  That is quite possibly POSIX-incompatible, and if it is, it could give you that very error.

Comment: no, im using the two lines from your last example as quoted above. It is simple not working.

Comment: That sounds like a bug, because there are no colons in that.

Comment: Zenexer and @kobame - BSD sed (incl. on macs) requires an argument to `-i`, specifying the backup suffix, so it's taking the `10s/.../` as that argument, leaving `test.php` as the command; the first `t` of that is being interpreted as a jump command to the label `est.php`, which doesn't exist, causing the error you are encountering. You can fix this by changing the `-i` to `-i .bak` or `-i ''`.

Answer (score 1):

For getting timezone is unfortunately not portable, but usually the /etc/localtime is an symbolic link to your timezone, so you can:

```
tz=$(readlink /etc/localtime | sed 's:\(.*\)/\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)$:\2/\3:')
echo ==$tz==
```

you will get your something like `==Europe/London==`. Now you can construct your string

```
time="date_default_timezone_set('$tz');"
```

and use it in the sed - but dont use `/` as delimiter (because the time sting containing it and confusing your sed)

```
sed -i "10s:.*:$time:" test.php
```

Comment: And what happens if your string changes to have a colon in it?

Comment: But theoretically, as code changes, it's possible that someone might add that character.  It's generally a better idea to escape everything.